# Dynamics 2011 SDK Generic "Add new record" function

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to write a generic C# function to add a new record to a given entity.
The trouble is that I can't tell what type each attribute is until I load an existing record, so I'm getting errors.
I'm sure there's a way to do this.

The following code fragment shows what I have:

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows) // <== gets data for new records from DataTable
{
    entity = new Entity(this.Entity); // <== an existing entity type
    Type columnType;
    foreach (SourceColumn column in this.Columns)
    {
        columnType = entity[column.Name].GetType(); // <== fails because not loaded
        entity[column.Name] = Convert.ChangeType(row[column.Name], columnType);
    }
    xrm.Create(entity);
}
```

What should I be doing instead?

Is there a way to load the entity definition without loading an entity record?

Thanks

Comment: Can You post how Your "Entity" class looks like ? or is this the default "Entity" class from EF ?

If so, then what You need is dynamic ;)

Comment: I'm not using the EF, it's the default Entity class from the CRM SDK; I'm using late bound classes because this is a generic function. I need something like `entity.LoadDefinitions` to add attributes and their types, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case you are best off using the metadata webservices.

If you use a `RetrieveAttributeRequest` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509035.aspx#BKMK_RetrieveAttribute).

Then that will return you a `RetrieveAttributeResponse` with `AttributeMetadata` ([MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata_members), which has property for `AttributeType`.

Comment: You could be right, but do I need to use the webservice to achieve this? This is for a periodic update so it might take too long to load every attribute of every entity which needs migrating...

Comment: Well, there are other functions that you can use, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603008 shows how to create a dump of all entity metadata in the system. You could perform this once at the beginning of the process and cache the results in memory or to disk.

Comment: It seems to me I might be better off loading a random record and getting the types from that!

Comment: But then you have to make sure that the record has all the fields populated. E.g. if you load a contact which only has the name populated I dont believe you will get information for phone number returned. Additionally you are then just swapping one web service call for another, so I'm not sure how that is better.

Comment: @bukko: if this is a periodic update, it shouldn't matter how long it takes to load each attribute, so long as they all show up. James's method *would* show all attributes, but as he mentioned, your method would more likely *not* get all attribute types.

Comment: The problem appears to be that one of the columns is an option set. So I think you are right; I need to get the entity definition and treat each attribute accordingly. Looking into that now...

Comment: I think I've got it, I just need to get an instance of IServiceProvider so I can call webservices (I was using the Xrm component before). Any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can You use reflection.

So Your code would look like this

```
var columnType = entity.GetType().GetProperties().First(p => p.Name == column.Name).GetType();
```

Comment: That gives "Sequence contains no matching element". I think because, again, it isn't really loaded yet. I need a way to load the definition without loading a record, if you see what I mean! :$

Comment: Does You entity contain the property with name = column.Name ?
You can try to do var props = entity.GetType().GetProperties(); and see what properties are there.

Comment: You may also need to specify binding flags for the method like :
...GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)

Comment: It's failing because there is no element for the specified key. The error is "Sequence contains no matching element"

Comment: This wont work in this case. Entity has an Attributes collection (which is what Entity[attributename] is accessing), thats basically a dictionary of <String, Object>, it is only populated with the with the data that is being used in that context. new Entity(entityname) just creates a 'blank' entity to add data to. Entity is used to dynamically communicate with Crm using the mscrm web services. You cannot guarentee that the attribute collection will actually contain any data.